# Can you give me an example of a wallet address

Tags: wallet, address

Bitcoin wallet address can anyone show me example

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Bitcoin:`1GVY5eZvtc5bA6EFEGnpqJeHUC5YaV5dsb`

Some Bitcoin addresses start with a 3. It is pretty much a 3 or a 1.

Before making transactions, always ensure that you are sending to and from a correct Bitcoin BTC address. There are other similarly named altcoins which have different symbols (not BTC) and those transactions do not work and Bitcoins will be lost. Sometimes the altcoin addresses even appear to be the same as a Bitcoin address. You really have to make sure both parties are dealing in proper Bitcoin BTC.

Comment: How or where do you get an  address, I am very computer illiterate

Comment: this question cannot be easily answered, as there are too many options. I suggest, you look at "www.bitcoin.org", and start from there. Also you can have a look at the ELECTRUM wallet, which is a good start. Whatever wallet you use, it will give you your first address.

Comment: @SelinaPyatte Good advice in the previous comment - head to [www.bitcoin.org](http://www.bitcoin.org/) and start to learn about Bitcoin and Wallet software there. A wallet is what you need to get a Bitcoin address and bitcoin.org is the official site.

Comment: @SelinaPyatte If my answer has helped you I would appreciate it if you would please mark it as accepted so that the question does not remain "unanswered".

Comment: Technically this is not a wallet address because a wallet is a collection

Comment: @OsiasJota And so, this is an example address from a collection of addresses, one example address from a wallet. The term example indicated one of. It would be true to say that this is not an example wallet, but that is not what is called for.